# Multi Page Selection VBO

Tags: views

Is there a way to achieve multi-page selection. Everytime I go to the next page, my selection gets lost. Any chance to keep my selection over multiple pages?

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch for same feature https://www.drupal.org/node/1207348